# Symfony2 form widgets for many-to-many relations

Tags: forms, symfony, many-to-many

In Symfony 1 there was as form widget named admin_double_list. It generated two select fields named Unassociated and Associated. It also generated buttons to add items from one list to another.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this in Symfony2? Or maybe some other user friendly way to edit many-to-many relations?

In the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) there are only four widgets for many-to-many relations and none of them are very nice when there are massive amount of relation possibilities to edit.

Answer (score 14):

You can easily manage many-to-many relationships with [entity form field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html). For example If `User` as a many-to-many relationship with `Group`, you can simply add to the builder:

```
$builder->add('groups', 'entity', array(
    'multiple' => true,   // Multiple selection allowed
    'expanded' => true,   // Render as checkboxes
    'property' => 'name', // Assuming that the entity has a "name" property
    'class'    => 'Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\Group',
);
```

This will generate a checkbox list where associated entities are marked (checked) while unassociated are not. Setting `expanded` to `false` you can render it as a select element (multiple one).

If you need to customize the way that groups are retrieved you can also pass a `query_builder` option, either `QueryBuilder` instance or a closure where `$er` is the `EntityRepository`

```
'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('g');

    return $qb->orderBy('g.name', 'DESC);
}
```

For more complex scenario look also at [collection form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html), but you have to deal with jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: The problem here is that there would be too many checkboxes for the edit page to be usable and user friendly. That is why I was looking for something similar to the Symfony1 way.

Comment: That'll do for me, for now. I was hoping to find a way to 'ajax' it so that a user could hit 'add another' and get another single select, until they picked all the associations they wanted, however.

Comment: How to change the way the MTM field is displayed, for exampe - display entities ids in a row of checkboxes, instead of default column?